# Reading PS3 Controller with LWJGL/JInput

Tags: input, lwjgl, joystick

I've been working on a project with the LWJGL for a while now and now I'm trying to add joystick support.  I have a PS3 controller plugged into a USB port and the following method that gets called in every game loop.

```
public synchronized void handleControllerEvents() {
    for (Controller controller : ControllerEnvironment
            .getDefaultEnvironment().getControllers()) {
        System.out.println(controller.getName());
        controller.poll();
        EventQueue eventQueue = controller.getEventQueue();
        Event event = new Event();
        while (eventQueue.getNextEvent(event)) {
            System.out.println(event);
        }
    }
}
```

The PS3 controllers name gets printed but I see no events coming out of it.  Every other input device is detected and generates events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit outdated but it was the topmost search result.

A PS3 controller will not automagically work on your Windows PC.
You will have to use a tool for this.
For example:
-DS3 Tool

I'm currently using this with my bluetooth PS3 controller.
Works splendid.

Comment: So are you using the bluetooth connection to use your PS3 controller with JInput? Can you give us some pointers about how to do that?

Comment: Again a very late reply. Yes the DS3 Tool will map the PS3 controller to XBOX360 controller input. I have created a class in a game engine which handles this logic with JInput: Hmpf... my site is offline. http://TomHash.NL somewhere in creations, moonshine framework. @salaboy